# Getting the size of a Blazor page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor

I'm learning JSInterop with Blazor.
I would like to get the width and the height of a Blazor page in oder to size à canvas.

I'm using the default Blazor template with the menu bar on the left part of the screen.
[image]

On the html part of the Canvas Test 1 page I have:

```
@page "/canvas_test1"
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
<canvas @ref="canvas1"></canvas>
<button @onclick="SetCanvasSize">Set canvas size</button>
```

In the code part I have:

```
ElementReference canvas1;
async Task SetCanvasSize()
{
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("SetCanvasSize", canvas1);
}
```

In the Javascript file I have:

```
function SetCanvasSize(element) {
ctx = element.getContext('2d');
console.log(window.innerWidth);
console.log(document.documentElement.scrollWidth);
}
```

But both methodes
*window.innerWidth* and  *document.documentElement.scrollWidth*
give the width of the entire window not only the page that contains the canvas.

How can I get the width of only the page without the side menu?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the dimensions of the containing element. You also need to listen for resizing events.

I use a service that can take a ref for any element and listen for changes.

`bCore.js`

```js
export function listenToWindowResize(dotNetHelper) {

    function resizeEventHandler() {
        dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('WindowResizeEvent');
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeEventHandler);

    dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('WindowResizeEvent');
}

export function getBoundingRectangle(element, parm) {
    return element.getBoundingClientRect();
}

export function getWindowSizeDetails(parm) {

    var e = window, a = 'inner';

    if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }

    let windowSize =
    {
        innerWidth: e[a + 'Width'],
        innerHeight: e[a + 'Height'],
        screenWidth: window.screen.width,
        screenHeight: window.screen.height
    };

    return windowSize;
}
```

`JSInteropCoreService.cs`

```cs
public class JSInteropCoreService : IJSInteropCoreService, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;
    private bool isResizing;
    private System.Timers.Timer resizeTimer;
    private DotNetObjectReference<JSInteropCoreService> jsInteropCoreServiceRef;

    public JSInteropCoreService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        this.resizeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval: 25);
        this.isResizing = false;
        this.resizeTimer.Elapsed += async (sender, elapsedEventArgs) => await DimensionsChanged(sender!, elapsedEventArgs);

        this.moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
          identifier: "import", args: "./_content/BJSInteroptCore/bCore.js").AsTask());
    }

    public event NotifyResizing OnResizing;
    public event NotifyResize OnResize;

    public async ValueTask InitializeAsync()
    {
        IJSObjectReference module = await GetModuleAsync();

        this.jsInteropCoreServiceRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

        await module.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "listenToWindowResize", this.jsInteropCoreServiceRef);

        this.BrowserSizeDetails = await module.InvokeAsync<BrowserSizeDetails>(identifier: "getWindowSizeDetails");

    }

    public async ValueTask<BrowserSizeDetails> GetWindowSizeAsync()
    {
        IJSObjectReference module = await GetModuleAsync();
        return await module.InvokeAsync<BrowserSizeDetails>(identifier: "getWindowSizeDetails");
    }

    public async ValueTask<ElementBoundingRectangle> GetElementBoundingRectangleAsync(ElementReference elementReference)
    {
        IJSObjectReference module = await GetModuleAsync();
        return await module.InvokeAsync<ElementBoundingRectangle>(identifier: "getBoundingRectangle", elementReference);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public ValueTask WindowResizeEvent()
    {
        if (this.isResizing is not true)
        {
            this.isResizing = true;
            OnResizing?.Invoke(this.isResizing);
        }
        DebounceResizeEvent();
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public BrowserSizeDetails BrowserSizeDetails { get; private set; } = new BrowserSizeDetails();

    private void DebounceResizeEvent()
    {
        if (this.resizeTimer.Enabled is false)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                this.BrowserSizeDetails = await GetWindowSizeAsync();
                isResizing = false;
                OnResizing?.Invoke(this.isResizing);
                OnResize?.Invoke();
            });
            this.resizeTimer.Restart();
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask DimensionsChanged(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.resizeTimer.Stop();
        this.BrowserSizeDetails = await GetWindowSizeAsync();
        isResizing = false;
        OnResizing?.Invoke(this.isResizing);
        OnResize?.Invoke();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            IJSObjectReference module = await GetModuleAsync();
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task<IJSObjectReference> GetModuleAsync()
        => await this.moduleTask.Value;
}
```

```
public class ElementBoundingRectangle
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Right { get; set; }
    public double Bottom { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
}
public class BrowserSizeDetails
{
    public double InnerWidth { get; set; }
    public double InnerHeight { get; set; }
    public int ScreenWidth { get; set; }
    public int ScreenHeight { get; set; }
}
```

I debounce the resize events using a 25ms interval to prevent lag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately as I'm a beginner your example is a bit to complicated to understand for me.  Additionnaly, I think I didn't explain correctly what I'm lookink for. In fact it's not the size of the canvas but the size of the page containing the canvas. Could you give me just a simple example on how I can retrieve the size of the page containing the canvas?  _window.innerWidth_ gives the width of the complete window, not the width of the page containing the canvas.

Comment: @Bert54 GetElementBoundingRectangleAsync returns the size of any HTML element. The reference can be captured using `@ref`. I provided a Service this needs an understanding of Dependency Injection

Comment: @Bert54 This should get you started. I extracted the relevant parts from my library.
https://github.com/BrianLParker/StackAsnswer_BoundingRectangle
Note the registration of the service in Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused about what a Page is in Blazor.  It's basically a component that you provide a route to for navigation.  If you include a layout (which is usually set by default), that is in fact part of the page.  All the things on the page, like your canvas, are just html elements.  It is correctly telling you the size of the window, which you can see will change if you resize your browser.

html elements have the properties "offsetWidth" and "offsetHeight."  So, for your use you want to pass the element to measure, and use `element.offsetWidth`:

```
function GetCanvasSize(element) {
     alert ("Element measurements: " + element.offsetWidth + ", " + element.offsetHeight);
}
```

You can see more of the members of html elements here, including common methods and events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

Note that this list is missing some important things you'd like to know, especially the various touch events which you'll need for dragging elements on mobile clients (mouse events won't work on phones).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in fact I think I didn't explain correctly what I'm lookink for. It is not the size of the canvas, but the size of the page or according your answer, the size of the component containing the canvas I must retrieve in order to adjust the size of the canvas accordingly.

Comment: The page includes the sidebar.  If you don't want the sidebar, you don't want the page.  If you want the "main" area (I think you do), then you can find the element by the "main" class in javascript.  Or you can add an id to that element and give it a unique name. 
 Look in your main layout page, and you will see that's where the @body content is located.